# adding cookieSameSite="None" to SessionState however still the SameSite value for the Cookie is Lax (Default)

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, httpcookie, samesite

In my web application I am iframing a different web application. The domain of both the webapplications are different.

I have following configuration for SessionState in web.config of the iframed web application.

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" sameSite="None"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.7.2" maxQueryStringLength="512" maxUrlLength="512" enableVersionHeader="false" />
    <sessionState mode="Custom" cookieless="UseCookies" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="245" cookieName="MYCOOKIE" cookieSameSite="None" customProvider="MyCustomSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <!-- Custom provider details -->
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <compilation batch="false" debug="false" />
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorMessage.aspx" mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

When I load the page the "MYCOOKIE" of the iframed page is not having SameSite set to none. Because of that MYCOOKIE is not send in subsequent HTTP request.

I am using chrome (**Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)**) and have enabled third party cookies.
IIS version 10.0
Installed .NET framework version in IIS is 4.8.03761

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Please use F12 to see if there are any errors or warnings in the console, and what browser are you using? As far as I know, some browsers are not compatible with SameSite or require users to enable this feature.

Comment: @samwu There are no console errors and I am using Chrome browser

Comment: What is your version of chrome? or you can try other browsers to see if it works.

Comment: @samwu I have mentioned the chrome version, IIS and .NET framework version. The problem exists in Edge. In firefox it works if I set network.cookie.sameSite.laxByDefault to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced the same issue earlier, after upgrading framework to 4.7.2 it wasn't working.

**FIX:**
-- All the installations of Windows has to be up-to-date as SameSite="None" comes with one particular Windows update.

Have a look: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4533011/kb4533011

Comment: Thanks. We required some Cumulative update for .NET framework 4.8 for windows server 2019